# Send dynamic data in $http.post from $scope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pyramid

My template can be found here http://goo.gl/xEttgl. I am hardcoding postData by declaring it as a global variable as

```
var postData = {'result': '27'};
app.factory('mypostService', function($http) {
return {
 postFooOldSchool: function() {
   $http.post('/angularresult', JSON.stringify(postData)
   ).success(function(data, status, headers){

   }).error(function(data, status, headers){

   });
  }
 }
});
app.controller('StartUpController', function($scope, $http, myService, mypostService) {
     $scope.upvotes = 0;
     $scope.serverupvotes = 0;
     $scope.increase = function(){
             $scope.upvotes = $scope.upvotes + 1;
     };
     mypostService.postFooOldSchool(function(data) {

     });
     myService.getFooOldSchool(function(data) {
            $scope.result = data;
     });
  });
```

but what i would like to do is send postData dynamically from $scope inside StartUpController i.e lets say i click upvote button and i want to send the current value of $scope.upvotes in POST and display it in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I over complicated the problem by using a factory, I found a simple solution, instead of using factory for POST i can directly send an $http.post request from the Controller. A sample solution is as follows

```
$scope.increase = function(){
    $scope.upvotes = $scope.upvotes + 1;
            var x = $scope.upvotes;
            alert(x)
            var postObject = {'result': x};
            $http.post('/angularresult', JSON.stringify(postObject)).success(function(data){
            });
            myService.getFooOldSchool(function(data) {
               $scope.result1 = data;

     });
     };
```

Comment: Not a good idea from a separation of concerns standpoint. It will make you controller harder to unit test as mocking the server side will be harder. You could have just passed $scope to your service function...